# React and Local Storage

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I am trying to make a scavenger hunt game with react and I would want the users to be able to save their inputs in local storage. However, when I tried implementing local storage inside my react app, my map function started giving me errors. Any help is appreciated.

```
class QuestionList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            answers:this.props.answers
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const pastAnswers = localStorage.getItem(`answers${this.props.url}`) ? localStorage.getItem(`answers${this.props.url}`) : this.props.answers

        this.setState({answers:  pastAnswers})

    }
    //answer should be a single letter
    handleAnswer (answer, num){
        let items=[...this.state.answers]
        items[num-1]=answer
        this.setState({answers:items})
        localStorage.setItem(`answers${this.props.url}`, items)

    }
renderList = this.props.questions.map((question, index)=>{

        return <QuestionCard
                 question={question} 
                 apiLink={this.props.url} 
                 bar_color_open={this.props.bar_color_open} 
                 bar_color_closed={this.props.bar_color_closed} 
                 onHandleAnswer={this.handleAnswer.bind(this)} 
                 key={index+1} 
                 number={index+1}  
                 />
    })


    render(){

        const answerList = this.state.answers.map((answer, index)=>{
            return <AnswerBox letter={answer} key={index}/>
        })

        return(
            <div className='list-container'>    
                <div className="grid-container_questions">
                    <div className={this.props.grid_container}> 
                        {answerList}
                    </div>
                    <div className='questionlist-container'>
                        {this.renderList}
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

If further code needs to be shown, just tell me and I will place the QuestionCards component up. I don't think, however, that it is needed as that component seems to be working fine.

edit: I have actually tried stringifying before stroing into local storage, but I keep getting this error:

Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: Are you sure its a localStorage issue? Cross-Origin is not related to localStorage, you may check this https://reactjs.org/docs/cross-origin-errors.html

Comment: Im not really sure myself, as this is the first time I am using local storage. I assumed it was the problem, as everything was working before I added it in my code.

Answer (score 1):

When storing an object in localstorage you first need to JSON.stringify it then when extracting you need to use JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, this was actually not a local storage problem. I looked into the docs that was linked to me: reactjs.org/docs/cross-origin-errors.html.
After adding crossorigin to the div with the id of root, everything started working again.